# Magento 2 : Show captcha at contact us form

Tags: magento2, contact-form

I use the below code in a CMS block to show the default magento contact us form.

```
<p>{{block 
    class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm"
    name="contactForm" 
    template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}</p>
```

Just wondering will there be a core way to enable captcha in the form?

Comment: https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html Give it a try

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to add CAPTHA to a Contact Us form you have to go to Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customers Configuration page and Enable CAPTCHA. Make sure to select Contact Us value in Forms field.

[image]

Once you update configuration, clean cache.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe the design Tab is only for page and not for the block.  Also the question I asked is how to show Captcha on the contact Us form which I dont believe you answer addresses that...

Comment: @Malaiselvan i completely missed the whole point of the question. It was long day yesterday. Let me write you an answer.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct.  However I realized that I do not need to create a block or a page for contact us.  All I need to do is enable Contact Us from Configuration and enable Catpcha for Contact Us.

Comment: Suppose i have created Custom Form & i want to add that in "Forms" list then how can i manage this?. So on my custom form also captcha will display

Comment: I want to use default captcha in newsletter form. so which kind of changes i shall make ?

Comment: Follow the answer and you are all set.

Comment: Very helpful, you saved my time!

Answer (score 5):

You can make a custom form template (based on the original) then you can load reCaptcha block programmatically whith this :

```
<?php 
    echo $block->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('MSP\ReCaptcha\Block\Frontend\ReCaptcha',
            'msp-recaptcha',
            ['data' => 
                [
                    'jsLayout' => 
                    [
                        'components' => 
                        [
                            'msp-recaptcha' => 
                            [
                                'component' => 'MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha',
                                'zone' => 'contact'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        )
        ->setTemplate('MSP_ReCaptcha::msp_recaptcha.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
    ?>
```