# Magento 2 Contacts Page has 2 versions

Tags: magento2, php, forms, contact-us, captcha

I'm trying to develop my contacts page but I'm receiving some unusual behaviour.

I've created the Contacts Page mydomain.com/contact and the contact form gets loaded via:

```
{{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" 
name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}
```

Here is form.html from my theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<div class="contact-us-page">

<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('google-map')->toHtml(); ?>

    <div class="row form-contact">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
<div class="contact-info">

<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('contact-store-info')->toHtml(); ?>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
    <form class="form contact"
          action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
          echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
          id="contact-form"
          method="post"
          data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
          echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <div class="title-bonus-page">
                <h2><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Send your comments') ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="left-input">
                <div class="field name required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Name*') ?>" name="name" id="name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Name') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field email required">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Email*') ?>" name="email" id="email" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Email') ?>" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field telephone">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Phone') ?>" name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field comment required">
                <div class="control">
                    <textarea placeholder="<?php echo __('Your Message*') ?>" name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('What’s on your mind?') ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value=""/>
                <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Send Message') ?>" class="action submit primary">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Send Message') ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This works great and displays everything correctly (No Captcha) however when I hit "Send Message" The Page reloads and asks for Captcha. It also changes the url. The new url has an /index/ on the end of it mydomain.com/contact/index/.

I'm not sure why its doing this. How can I get the page to load correctly with Captcha on mydomain.com/contact

Comment: Check into your model or controller file that whether it is checking for the captcha into your response? [you can refer this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97114/magento-2-show-captcha-at-contact-us-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**index** is nothing but an action name by default you could load the contact us page by

www.domain.com/contact/index and it does return the same page. So if you do not want that **index** to append in the sense you can remove it in below file.

> vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php

replace this

> return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact/index');

with this

> return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('contact/');

Of course you have override the **post** **controller** in you custom module.

Then if you want to configure the captcha to you form in the sense you can configure it in admin by

> Stores->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->Enable Captcha -> You can select and save your form.

Hope this information helps you :)